# Rally - assign a parent project's iteration to an imported child project

Tags: rally

searched for answers to this keyword set and don't see anything. There's a master project in my Rally implementation master with some child projects as so:

### As-is:

1. Master Project 1(master iteration 1)

   1. Child Project A (master iteration plan 1)
   2. Child Project B (master iteration plan 1)

   Master Project 2 (master iteration plan 2)

Now there's a request to move master project 2 under master project 1 as a child project, and for MP 2 to use master iteration plan 1 instead of master iteration plan 2.

### To-be:

1. Master Project 1(master iteration 1)

   1. Child Project A (master iteration 1)
   2. Child Project B (master iteration 1)
   3. Child Project C - (Master Project 2) (currently master iteration plan 2, desired to share master iteration plan 1)

My question:

1. How do I change the Child Project C's iteration from iteration 1 to iteration 2?
2. What effect will changing the iteration have on Child Project C (former master project 2) stories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to question 1 - you will need to update the current iteration in Child Project C that matches the settings from the iteration you already have created in your Master Project 1. This will ensure that all of the data rolls up properly.  Going forward, when you create new iterations you can use the "Create Matching Iterations in all Child Projects" checkbox to create the iterations all the way down the hierarchy.

In answer to your second question - all of the data you currently have scheduled will be there, however making changes to the original iteration in Child Project C could affect your project burndown given that the dates were most likely changed.  I recommend that you finish out the current iterations as they are.  When they are compete you can then create a new iteration altogether that will be populated down the entire project hierarchy.

Comment: This is what we wound up doing - thanks. Just realized I never accepted this answer.